# Using \equiv causes my font to become italicized and doesn't allow spacing

Tags: spacing, equations, formatting, italic, logicproof

I am trying to write a logic equation with symbols and when I use \equiv everything afterwards is italics and does not allow spacing, even if I go to a new line.

Example:

p \to q \equiv \lnot q \to \lnot p

Output:

p → q ≡ ¬*q*→¬*p*

I have attempted to put the \equiv between $ but that also didn't work.

Also if I try to type on the next line it doesn't go to the next line, the only way I can go to the next line is by using \\ and even when I do that the next line is still italicized and there are no spaces.

I am new to LaTeX and stackexchange but can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: could you add a MWE?

Comment: You need `$p \to q \equiv \lnot q \to \lnot p$`.

Comment: You have to put the expression between dollar signs, if you don't want p and q to be in italic than put them in \mathrm{}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Internet sites like this one are great for providing brilliant solutions to tough issues, but if you accept a piece of unsolicited advice, you should not try to use them as a substiute for technical manuals.  In particular, I recommend that you don’t try to write LaTeX code without having read at least an introductory guide.